# Why can't I debug my Android project over the phone?

Tags: android

I'm just getting into the field of Android development and I need to run my project for the first time in order to continue my learning process.
Unfortunately my computer is'nt powerful enough to run an AVD and every time I try to debug it with my phone I get this error message:

> A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest'
>
>  (type' ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest').
> File 'E:\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\out\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for
> property 'mainMergedManifest' does not exist.

**General Information:**
I'm trying to debug a brand new project using my Galaxy A 70 (running Android 10). If necessary I would be happy to provide any additional information (to the best of my ability) regarding the project, the specifications of my phone or computer, etc.

**build.gradle of app module:**

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

---

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I would be very grateful for any help regarding this problem.
Thanks in advance
Perry

Comment: can you share your build.gradle of app module

Comment: please create a `debug`  buildTypes with `debuggable` flag as true

Answer (score 0):

You need a debug build type that is set to debuggable true

Add this to your buildTypes in build.gradel

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
      debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Then run gradle sync. [image: Gradle Sync], and in the build variants [image: Select build variants]select the **debug** configuration, and then you'll be able to debug your app

Comment: I feel so dumb now because these steps are really simple (PS thanks for the addition of the pictures I would not have been able to find these buttons without them :) but unfortunately the problem still exists.

Comment: do you get a different error message ? or the same one ?

Comment: could you post your AndroidManifest.xml file please ?

Comment: It's the same one

Comment: another thing to try is to run clean before you build the app - does running the app work ?

Comment: tbh I'm not sure I know what the differences are between them, but one way or another I get the same message

Comment: You need to make sure SDKs 18 and 29 are installed on your computer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65055913/android-mainmergedmanifest-does-not-exist