# A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest' while running default code in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, manifest

- Flutter Doctor: [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.0, on Microsoft
  Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985], locale -IN) [√] Android toolchain -
  develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3) [√] Chrome -
  develop for the web [√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0) [√] Connected
  device (3 available) • No issues found!

Comment: Can you add full error message to the question?

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest' (type 'ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest').
> File 'D:\project\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\out\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'mainMergedManifest' does not exist.

Comment: this is the full error message that was shown.

Comment: Try solution by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65055913/android-mainmergedmanifest-does-not-exist) link.